# Create MongoClient with MongoClientSettings in C# with connection string

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb.driver

I'm just looking for a way to initialize a `MongoClient` using `MongoClientSettings` with a provided connection string.

Can not find any example of this on the project website. These are all their examples:

```
// To directly connect to a single MongoDB server
// (this will not auto-discover the primary even if it's a member of a replica set)
var client = new MongoClient();

// or use a connection string
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");

// or, to connect to a replica set, with auto-discovery of the primary, supply a seed list of members
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way you can do this :

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString("ConnectionString");
// change some fields based on your needs
settings.WaitQueueTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
settings.MinConnectionPoolSize = 100;
settings.MaxConnectionPoolSize = 500;
```

And create the `MongoClient` using this command:

```
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
```